# Merge translation files (.ts) with existing .ts files using QT Utilities (lconvert)

Tags: qt, translation

Here's my problem:  We've got .ts files for nine different languages for our product.  We've added about 100 new strings that need to be translated, but some are for our next release, and some are for the release after that.  We've run into problems with translators missing strings or translating strings ahead of time.  We want to be able to send them smaller .ts file containing only the strings we want translated now, and then merge that .ts file into the larger .ts file containing the rest of the translation.

Our translators are required to use QT Linguist (previously we let them edit the raw XML with less than stellar results).

One solution would be to use contexts, but our dev team is not very keen on that idea.  Another would be to merge the .ts files by hand, but that seems like a recipe for cut & paste errors.

Is there a method with lupdate & the project file to add or merge secondary .ts files?  I've read through the forums in QT-land w/o finding the answer, but the switches in lupdate allude to being able to point to other translation files.  Specifically the -pro switch which says:

```
    -pro <filename>
       Name of a .pro file. Useful for files with .pro file syntax but
       different file suffix. Projects are recursed into and merged.
```

Example1:  we have a German .ts file, we want to add 20 strings from a separate German translation file such that the primary translation file contains all the strings including the 20 new ones.

Example2:  we have a German .ts file, we want to add 20 strings from a separate German translation file such that the secondary translation file will be merged with the primary during lupdate so that the resultant .qm file contains all the strings including the 20 new ones.

Has anyone done either of these (and either would work) and can you give me some insight?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The answer doesn't use lupdate, it lies in another utility called lconvert.  It's quite easy to create a secondary file that only contains the strings you're interested in (and  delete those same strings from the primary file), then run:

`lconvert -i primary.ts secondary.ts -o complete.ts`

This will take all the strings from the two input files and put them together into the output file.  Using this method I was able to create a zero difference file (other than time stamp) of the original file that I'd split the two primary & secondary files from.

This question didn't get a lot of attention, but maybe someone will have this same problem and this will help.

Comment: You can find out how to install **lconvert** tools using this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/474236/error-installing-avogadro-with-cmake-lconvert-could-not-exec-no-such-file-or-d. Thanks. Just install `qttools5-dev-tools`.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for this tip. It seems to work properly for my case : 
I tried to extract updated and new strings from my project, which is currently under translation in an older version/release that I do not already have translated strings.

The problem was to send the new/updated strings only to translators.

I passed older strings in status resolved, adding new string using Lupdate, make a research using OxygenXML Editor with an XPath "/TS/context/message[not(translation/@type)]" to delete older strings, and clean it from useless blanks and carriage returns.

I tried a merge using lconvert with your solution, in order to merge translated strings : older and newer. It pass correctly lrelease and are displayed properly.

Comment: glad this worked for you.  As a point of SO etiquette, generally, if an answer works for you, you'd click on the up arrow of that answer and optionally add a comment to clarify how it worked for you, instead of adding an answer that should have really just been a comment on the original answer.  No worries though.